# Perl Simple hash delete by value

Tags: regex, perl, hash

I have a hash in Perl which stores a simple key value look up as shown below

```
'a' => hello
'b' => world
'c' => hellooo
```

I would like to efficiently delete all key value pairs that have the pattern "hello" in them. Is this easily possible through `grep`
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [hash slice](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices) here. Hash slices return the values associated with a list of keys.

To **remove** key/value pairs at once, you could do something like this..

```
my $regex = qr/hello/;
delete @h{ grep { $h{$_} =~ $regex } keys %h };
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for (keys %h) {
   delete $h{$_} if $h{$_} =~ /hello/;
}
```

```
delete $h{$_} for grep { $h{$_} =~ /hello/ } keys %h;
```

```
delete @h{ grep { $h{$_} =~ /hello/ } keys %h };
```

Comment: Can you explain each solution, and how it differs from the others?  This should be an educational answer, rather than a quick fix.

Comment: @PaulHicks With respect, if the OP is informed enough to be able to suggest the type of answer he wants (namely `grep`), then he should be informed enough to decipher or look up the basic options demonstrated in these 3 examples.

Comment: @Paul Hicks, He should pick whichever one he finds more readable.

Comment: I wasn't really thinking of the OP.  I was thinking of future readers.

Comment: @Paul Hicks, They should pick whichever they find more readable too.